# Why does accessing my NSMutableArray become faster once I've added more objects to it?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Something very odd is going on. I populate my array as follows:

```
self.workingWithItemCollectionArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:self.itemCollectionArray.count];
self.workingWithItemCollectionArray = [[self.itemCollectionArray mutableCopy]autorelease];
```

It take a mutable copy of the original `NSArray` and pass it to the `NSMutableArray`. When accessing the information contained in this array by the click of a `UIButton`, there is a slight delay in retrieving the information.

But when I then change the original array to add more items, and then pass this onto the mutable array:

```
NSMutableArray *editedOriginalArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.itemCollectionArray];
[editedOriginalArray addObjectsFromArray:extraObjectsToAdd];
self.itemCollectionArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:editedOriginalArray];

self.workingWithItemCollectionArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:self.itemCollectionArray.count];
self.workingWithItemCollectionArray = [[self.itemCollectionArray mutableCopy]autorelease];
```

It is then after this that I am able to press the button and information is accessed instantly (whereas before the button would stay pressed for a very short time).

Any ideas on why this could be?

Comment: Note that your line `self.workingWithItemCollectionArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:self.itemCollectionArray.count];` is completely unnecessary, as it just wastes CPU cycles creating an empty array, and then deleting it on the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with how `NSMutableArray` is implemented vs `NSArray`.

Because `NSArray` is immutable, the objects are literally internally stored in an array, e.g.:

```
id *objects = malloc(sizeof(id) * count);
```

However, when you deal with `NSMutableArray`, you are dealing with instead, a linked list, as `NSMutableArray` expects many modifications on the array. So, the lookup on a linked list is much longer, because your objects are not stored in a way where there is a set distance in memory between them.

For more information on linked lists, check [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_List).

Comment: Are you saying that larger mutable array is processed `faster` then a smaller mutable array because mutable arrays implementation implies more functions in the cost of speed ? To put it short, is it really happened that mutable array was processed `faster` because it is `slower` ? :)

Comment: @A-Live Yup, as far as my understanding of the internals of NSArrays are, its how it works...

Comment: oh my, that's fantastic, i'll need to think more about that concept. My first guess was that immutable array (itself or  with some runtime helper as you are saying it has only `id*count` bytes) stored some index information while it was first converted to a mutable so that during `addObjectsFromArray` a new mutable array was partially indexed. Interesting, maybe you have some advanced reference to dig it deeper ?

Comment: What's really odd, is that if I'm dealing with an array with 1,000 objects, and then add only 1 more, it is processed faster.

Comment: @Sooper go figure. One thing I have read is that NSArray will actually change it's internal representation if the number of objects inside it reaches a certain threshold, e.g. from an array list to a linked-list, but I haven't actually experienced that. All I can tell you is that for most 'normal' situations, NSArray is a true array, whilst NSMutableArray is a linked list. This is purely from my experiences with the APIs, and some performance testing.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Interesting stuff, thanks for the info! I've switched over to using only NSArrays and still getting the same results. I think I'll do some testing of my own and post anything I think to be useful.