# Does retrieval from NSArray exhibit cache locality?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, caching

When looping through a normal C array, the CPU intelligently grabs surrounding cells from RAM and sticks them in CPU cache. The CPU knows that if you're grabbing index 6, you're likely going to need index 7 soon after. Do Objective-C NSArrays also exibit [locality of reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference)?

```
for (id item in array) {
  NSLog(@"%@", item);
}

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < array.count; i++) {
  NSLog(@"%@", array[i];
}
```

People working outside of Apple don't have the internal implementation of NSArray. However, one can guess that NSMutableArray is likely implemented with a linked list since it has methods to slice the array from any index. If we assume that NSArray is backed by the same data store as NSMutableArray, then all NSArray do not exhibit locality of reference.

The reason I ask is that I'm optimizing UITableViewCell height calculations by storing the heights in a cache. The cache would be more easily implemented as an NSMutableDictionary than NSMutableArray, so that I don't have to deal with gaps in arrays (which are not allowed). If NSArray provides locality of reference, then I would switch to NSArray for extra performance and endure this extra complexity.

Comment: a) It's not CPU intelligence, it's cache levels and memory page sizes.
b) Why don't you implement it the easy way first? I struggle to imagine that a dictionary lookup on the height of a cell is going to be the critical performant section of your application!

Comment: "that NSMutableArray is likely implemented with a linked list since it has methods to slice the array from any index." – um what? first of all no it's not, it's implemented as a circular buffer; second, why would you come to this conclusion from that premise…?!

Comment: "People working outside of Apple don't have the internal implementation of NSArray." The underlying implementation of NSArray is CFArray, which is open source. We absolutely have the implementation. http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-1153.18/CFArray.c

Comment: BTW, what baseline performance profiling have you done to establish that this is your bottleneck, and that you can use to compare your improvements? Belief in "locality of reference" should not be enough to cause you to inject complexity. You need to write test code that demonstrates that the complexity delivers actual benefits in real code. In my experience, trying to outsmart Foundation often leads to slower results; you must test very carefully to make sure you're seeing real improvements.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Another person saying NSMutableArray is implemented with a linked list: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9810143/459987

Comment: @RobNapier I ran profiler on my program and height calculation is the most expensive part of my app. There are many labels inside the cell. Calculation of text size is quite expensive. I've also profiled NSDictionary before to access about 20 items. Key generation and accessing by key was about 30 times more expensive than all the crazy physics calculations I was doing on each of the items. I don't know what explains that. It should be constant time access, but that constant can be huge. But if there are a lot of collisions, it's no longer constant.

Comment: If you're seeing non-trivial lookup times in a 20-item `NSDictionary`, then you're almost certainly using the wrong key type. Your key either takes too long to copy (if the problem is during writes), or too long to hash/isEqual (if the problem is during reads).

Comment: Or do you mean you're accessing 20 items out of a massive dictionary? That sounds like you're doing too much work in rowHeight; you should compute the final result when the data is updated, not lots of intermediate results you still have to glue together. You should also strongly consider whether to redesign your cell. Cells often are not performant when they require many subviews (particularly during scrolling).

Comment: I was accessing all 20 items out of a dictionary with 20 items. The key was a pointer stored in a NSValue. `NSValue *key = [NSValue valueWithPointer:(__bridge const void * _Nullable)(someObject)]; AnotherObject *anotherObject = _someDictionary[key];`. I'll try switching to an `NSMapTable` so I can directly use the pointer as the key. I'll see if this is better performance. `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is expensive in a large table because `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` calls `heightForRowAtIndexPath` on every cell from 0 to `numberOfRowsInIndexPath` regardless of whether it is visible or not.

Comment: @JoJo I don't know from where that person pulled that sort of information off. [Here's an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22591296/what-is-the-data-structure-behind-nsmutablearray) referring to a blog post in which the author **actually reverse engineered the implementation** of `NSMutableArray`, and it was a circular buffer.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Circular buffer and queues are not mutually exclusive. Wikipedia on circular buffer: *Circular buffering makes a good implementation strategy for a queue that has fixed maximum size.*

Comment: @JoJo **you did not write "queue".** You wrote **"linked list".**